# Is there any better way to move a window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmouseevent

I am working on an application with Qt Framework for desktop. Since I remove every window decoration I had to implement the main window to receive move event from when the user click on it and move the mouse around.

I tried the following code but I am not satisfied. I wonder if there is any better way to this with more elegance.

```
QPoint* mouseOffset; //global variable that hold distance of the cursor from 
                       the top left corner of the window.

void ArianaApplication::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
     move(event->screenPos().x() - mouseOffset->x(),
          event->screenPos().y() - mouseOffset->y());
}

void ArianaApplication::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
     mouseOffset = new QPoint(QCursor::pos().x() - pos().x(),
                              QCursor::pos().y() - pos().y());
}
```

Would you suggest me something else?

Comment: Lots of types in Qt can be handled like values, i.e. you should not be manually allocating memory for them. It's the compiler's job to do it. Every single `new` in your code should have a rationale behind it. I'd guess that 9 out of 10 `new`s in SO Qt questions are unnecessary. `QPoint` is a value type!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method is correct, but the implementation can be improved in the following points:

- `mouseOffset` is not necessary to be a pointer, since you are creating dynamic memory unnecessarily and you have the responsibility to eliminate it.
- It is not necessary to obtain each component, `QPoint` supports [subtraction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpoint.html#operator--1).

***.h**

```
QPoint mouseOffset;
```

***.cpp**

```
void ArianaApplication::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
     move(event->globalPos() - mouseOffset);
}

void ArianaApplication::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
     mouseOffset = event->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
}
```